# How would I pipe a command to grep to search for a certain string, when part of that string is unknown?

Tags: command-line, grep, format, string

The program I am working on makes use of `grep` to search a system log for a particular alert, however the an element of the syslog entry I am looking for will pertain specifically to that entry, and therefore be effectively “random.”

An example of what I think I’m looking for would be:

```
tail -f log | grep "string {ignore} string"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use **[WildCards (or Globbing Patterns)](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)**  in the `grep` command like this :

```
 tail -f log | grep "some_string.*some_string"
```

Where, **`.*`** (Also pointed by @dsstorefile1 in the comments) is the globbing pattern used here. To get more details on Globbing Patterns refer to manpages.

---

```
man 7 glob
```

Which will show this :

```
     . (dot) : will match any single character (except end of line) , 
               equivalent to ? (question mark) in standard wildcard expressions.

* (asterisk) : the proceeding item is to be matched zero or more times.
               ie. n* will match n, nn, nnnn, nnnnnnn
                           but not na or any other character.
```

Now, Combining both of these you get :

```
.* (dot and asterisk) : match any string, equivalent to * in standard wildcards.
```

Also, as pointed by @Bob in comments, using **`.*?`** is much better than `.*`

Comment: `.*` is greedy and might capture more than you want. `.*?` is usually better.

Comment: That has nothing to do with "`?` in place of `.`". Read my comment again - the `?` is a modifier on `*`, making it lazy instead of the greedy default. Assuming PCRE.

Comment: I should also point out that this is regex (grep doing POSIX regex by default), not a shell glob.

Comment: @Bob edited my answer and Could you please clarify more about How `.*` is more greedy and using `.*?` instead.

Comment: Read this: https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html, especially the "Watch Out for The Greediness!" amd "Laziness Instead of Greediness" sections. See also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions

Comment: [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) != [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)